# MySql Subtract a table from another

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: A contains all the data, table B created from A selecting %25 of its data randomly. So A and B have exact same columns. Also there is no unique column.

What I want to do is subtract B from A. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused when you say subtract.  Do you mean filter?  If you filter one table on another you need to decide what column or columns that relate between the two table you would like to base your filter pattern.

Comment: Yes, I want to filter out all data ,that already in B, from A

Comment: You want to remove any fields that appear in B from the A table, so there's no common entries anymore?

Comment: I assume this is just a mind game, no serious application that you can describe?

Comment: I am sorry for late reply. There is a bunch of data, unfortunately there is no unique column. I want to take %25 of sample data randomly and create another table. And for the rest %75 of data I can create another table or crop the original one... It is important that %75 of data doesn't include the data that is already in %25 part.

Answer (score 13):

To view all rows in `A` except those in `B`:

```
SELECT * FROM A
WHERE (field1, field2, ..., fieldN) NOT IN
( SELECT *
  FROM B
) ;
```

To actually delete from table `A` the rows that are in `B`:

```
DELETE FROM A
WHERE (field1, field2, ..., fieldN) IN
( SELECT *
  FROM B
) ;
```

Comment: @Conrad: It works in my copy of MySQL (5.0.51). Which version did you tested it in?

Comment: My mistake I made a non-edit so I could change my vote, and  I deleted my comment

Comment: Or simply `B` instead of `( SELECT * FROM B )`.

Comment: @mareoraft `WHERE (field1, field2, ..., fieldN) IN B` is not valid syntax.

Comment: `WHERE (field1, field2, ..., fieldN) IN (TABLE B)` is however and supported in MySQL 8.0.

Answer (score 2):

I have a very similar requirement to you except that for mine, B is just a subset of A.
If you're still looking for an answer:

```
SELECT * FROM A WHERE NOT EXIST 
 (SELECT * FROM B WHERE A.field1 = B.field1 AND A.field2 = B.field2 etc)
```

You would need to specify the same condition as doing an inner join on A and B.

Comment: It should be `EXISTS` with an 'S' in MySQL

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're comparing multiple fields you'll need to either use exists or join. since you're looking to delete its easier yi just use exists.

```
        delete from
        Tablea
        Where
         Exists(
              Select 1 
               from tableb
              where tablea.fielda = tableb.fielda 
                    And tablea.fieldb = Tableb.fieldb
                   And...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a unique key (it can just be a sequential number)on the original table and the you can select matched or unmatched records ( the 25% or the inverse)

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend making a ID column with auto increment, <strike>but if you can't just do:</strike>

<strike>DELETE FROM a WHERE a.c1 = (SELECT c1 FROM b) AND a.c2 = (SELECT c2 FROM b) AND a.c3 = (SELECT c3 FROM b)</strike>

Sorry, just realized it only works for one row...

Well, then the only thing i got is making an ID column, sorry...