# mySQL query to Retrieve only the records in left table

Tags: mysql, database, join

How to write a mysql query to get **only** the records in left table.
Left Join gives me all the records from T1 table and there is no `MINUS` in mySQL.

[image: only left]

**EDIT:**
Do not wish to use sub queries

Comment: Similar question already exists I believe:
[Subtract a table from another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738240/mysql-subtract-a-table-from-another)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  are looking for a left excluding join

```
  SELECT  A.*
  FROM Table_A A
  LEFT JOIN Table_B B
  ON A.Key = B.Key
  WHERE B.Key IS NULL
```

See this Article on SQL join, it can be helpful
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Answer (score 4):

Use `not exists`:

```
select l.*
from `left` l
where not exists (select 1 from `right` r where r.id = l.id);
```

If you need more column comparisons, you can expand the logic:

```
select l.*
from `left` l
where not exists (select 1
                  from `right` r
                  where r.col1 = l.col1 and
                        r.col2 = l.col2 and
                        . . .
                 );
```

Comment: Was actually looking for a query without any sub-queries.Thank you.